# Getting request attributes with gRPC cals

Tags: rest, filter, playframework, grpc, prometheus

I have a micro-service (Play 2.8) in which I have implemented Prometheus filters for route latency and total http count. I have a router for the gRPC service and a REST controller for a secondary purpose. My filters are able to use the Router.Attrs.HandlerDef object to access the request's path, controller name, verb, etc when the request is made to the REST controller. However, this method does not work when I make a gRPC call to the router, thus I cannot see request attributes like path, etc. So, my question is Router.Attrs.HandlerDef not able to function with gRPC requests?